# I keep getting shapes outlined on the model when rendering in cycles when using specific nodes from the shader editor

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders, shader-nodes, denoise

Usually whenever I render in cycles, either when using the glossy node, the glass node, or the translucent node in the shader editor, I have shapes within the model showing up. How to fix? Is this something with denoising?

[image]

[image]

This is the car only
[image]

Comment: Hello Alex! Would you please upload a packed file at https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: maybe you need to Clear Custom Split Normals Data?

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: @moonboots  how?

Comment: in the Object Data panel > Geometry Data > Clear Custom...

Comment: @EvripidisLalissidis I have uploaded the packed blend file. Could you please take a look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have multiple problems in this scene.

1. Enter *Edit Mode* select all faces by pressing *A* then press *M* to *merge by distance*
2. While in *Edit Mode*, select the *Face* dropdown and select *Tris to Quads*
3. check your normals by opening the "*Overlays*" and selecting "*show face orientation*".

[image]

4. Press ALT + N and *Recalculate Outside* or *Recalculate Inside* (Experiment and try out the best solution so all your Mesh is Blue on the outside!
5. Your Layer Weight Material node (Black to Red) will highlight every inconsistency in your mesh typology. If you want to keep it you have to do some heavy Typology fixing.
6. Select edges that break the "Material flow" and press *X* + *dissolve Edges*.

[image]
[image]

7. Repeat this step everywhere you have to.