# Shadding artifacts in transparency Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, transparency

I have an object which has a transparent bsdf applied on the surface. But there are these weird artifacts in the object. The topology is largely clear because I'm using simple Booleans and Bevels. How can I get rid of these?

[image]

Comment: try changing the blending method to alpha hashed

Comment: Hello and welcome! kindly share your blend file https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: Hey! Have a look at this answer :) https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/280681/130757

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing more of your project, but often booleans create n-gons which then cause shading problems. It also looks like there might be some z-fighting as well, but it's hard to tell from the image.